# Why there are no READMEs in the Linux filesystem hierarchy?

Tags: documentation, fhs

The Linux filesystem hierarchy ([FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)) contains a lot of important directories. For example, I just discovered `/sys/class/input` while playing with my PS/2 keyboard settings.

But all those important directories are documented elsewhere, so `man /sys/class/input` doesn't work to explain what happens at a certain point.

Why not place `README` files into the hierarchy to make it easier for people to learn what's going on at certain levels and play with the contents? It would be really awesome if devices could even mount their own `README`s.

Comment: Perhaps because most people don't want to learn what is going on at those different levels?  They just want them to work, so they can accomplish whatever tasks they need/want to do.  Someone would have to write all those README files, and they'd add more bloat to a file system already overloaded with things (like much of /usr/share) that most people will never use.

Comment: @jamesqf _because most people don't want to learn what is going on at those different levels? They just want them to work, so they can accomplish whatever tasks they need/want to do_ And what if my task is related to the file system, like the OP's seems to be? Also, have you met a Linux user? We *do* want to learn. This is a terrible argument.

Comment: The fundamental difference between Linux and Windows/Mac, in case you have not noticed, is that Linux knows that you left the womb already knowing everything. Hence a README would be redundant.

Comment: @kaqqao: Well, I AM a Linux user, and have been one pretty much since there WAS a Linux.  And before that a user of Unix since it ran on my school's PDP-11.  I don't particularly care how things like the file system work, I just (at the moment) want to get my seismic tomography code working.  Nor do I care about /sys/class/input, as long as my keyboard & trackball work.  For the small minority who are interested in these things, there is a handy tool called Google, accessible from most web browsers :-)

Comment: It isn't very future-proof from an i18n standpoint, amongst other issues.

Comment: There's `man hier`.

Answer (score 30):

To use your example: `/sys/` doesn't contain "real" files, but is entirely provided by the kernel. Do you want all READMEs to become part of the kernel? You probably don't.

Documentation is in `/usr/share/doc`. Which contains normal files on your harddisk. Some documentation about `/sys` and `/proc` is in the kernel source, that is in `/usr/src/linux/Documentation` (if you've installed the kernel source, and made the symlink for your current kernel).

Comment: I don't see why README would hurt kernel distribution. Or do you imply that everything that is part of the kernel is loaded in memory?

Comment: sysfs and procfs are fully virtual filesystems that have no backing store. Everything in there is synthesized on the fly by the kernel. If the READMEs are not stored in memory, where else would they come from?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Obviously the kernel could synthesise symlinks to `/use/share/doc`.

Comment: The kernel is already a large and complicated piece of software, and "making it easier for people to learn" is not among the main goals of their developers. It's not *that* hard to go to `/usr/share/doc` instead.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni `grep -R "/sys/class/input" /usr/share/doc` - nothing is there.

Comment: @MSalters: that would mean that the kernel has to either a) scan the entire filesystem to find those files and create symlinks to them, b) has to have a load of configuration options to tell the kernel where those files are so that it can create symlinks to them, or c) has to prescribe the locations of those files to the distribution maintainers (which would violate Linus's #1 maxim that policy belongs in userspace, only mechanism belongs in the kernel). Also, how do you make sure that the files match up with the currently running kernel version? What about distributions which have their …

Comment: … documentation in `/Documentation` instead of `/usr/share/doc`? How do you provide translations?

Comment: @JörgWMittag The FHS [specifies](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#usrshareArchitectureindependentData) that if documentation is installed, then `/usr/share/doc` must be present, at least as a symlink. I presume that distros which use `/Documentation` have a symlink.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: the FHS is only mandatory for Linux distributions conforming to the LSB. Most don't. In particular, there are a number of distributions which were *specifically* founded to *clean up* (what they perceive as) historical cruft, which in many cases *explicitly* includes the FHS.

Comment: Ahhh, the great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from, and you can make your own...

Comment: @MichaelHampton: one of my favorite saying (.. and one of the greatest cause of pb nowadays). And there is even an xkcd for that: https://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 14):

Because Unix and Linux have a decades old tradition of documenting with [`man` pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) (and, on GNU systems, [`info` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_(Unix)) ...). See [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html), [man(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man.7.html), [man-pages(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html). BTW, `man` command and pages are *optional* (and you won't install them on every Unix system).

The file system hierarchy is described in [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html).

It is defined by the [Filesystem Hierachy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) available on https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/fhs

Several filesystems, notably `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) and `/sys/` (see [sysfs(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html)) are pseudofile systems provided by the kernel code. You don't want to bloat the kernel with extra code producing such `README`-s (which is useless to the vast majority of users). Even the kernel's configuration file is only *optionally* available as `/proc/config.gz` which is often *disabled* in most kernel configurations. And many Linux systems are embedded systems (e.g. your smartphone, your smart appliance or IoT device, your RaspberryPI) where resources are scare enough to avoid being wasted.

Notably `/sys/` is mostly useful to sysadmins and to developers writing low-level utilities, and both are supposed to be able to find documentation appropriately.

> Why not to place `README` files into the hierarchy to make it easier for people to learn what's going on

If you really want such `README`s,  write your own [loadable kernel module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module) providing them, or setup some [unionfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) to provide them. I don't think it is worth the effort (and a unionfs on `/sys` would probably slow down your entire system).

Remember that kernel code consumes RAM (it is never paged out and sits in *physical* memory, not virtual memory), even if not used. So it makes sense to avoid bloating it.

Comment: So I can write a package that documents all those paths without touching kernel or making it bloat?

Comment: You could, but using a *unionfs* on `/sys` would slow down your system. I don't think it is worth losing your time in such way. Life is short... And you'll spend more time doing that than reading the documentation